# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid when trying to sort on an associated field.

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I am trying to sort results based on an associated field. I found posts indicating that this could be done with includes.

I have an observation model that has

```
  before_validation   :parse_supervisor, :parse_employee

  has_many :attachments, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments

  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "employee_id", class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "supervisor_id", class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :department
```

I have a user.rb that includes the following. User.rb is also used with adauth for active directory integration but I don't believe that is causing the problems.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


  has_many :subordinates, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "supervisor_id"

  belongs_to :supervisor, class_name: "User"
   has_many :observations
```

Part of my observations\index.rb is as follows. The user.

```
 <% @observations.each do |observation| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= observation.employee_id %></td>
        <td><%= observation.user.first_name %></td>
        <td><%= observation.user.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= observation.user.id %></td>
        <% d = observation.date %>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><%= d.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %></td>
        <td><%= observation.status %></td>
```

The `observation.user.first_name` and last_name works for display.

My observations controller has

```
 def index
    @observations = Observation.all
    @users = User.all
    get_ldap('*', '*')
    @observations = Observation.includes([:users]).order('[user].last_name ASC')
```

I put user in brackets [] because it appears that user is a reserved word in sql.

The error I am getting is

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Observations#index
Showing C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/employee_observations/app/views/observations/index.html.erb where line #23 raised:

TinyTds::Error: The multi-part identifier "user.last_name" could not be bound.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [eo].[observations].* FROM [eo].[observations]  ORDER BY [user].last_name ASC'
Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/employee_observations

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/observations/index.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_observations_index_html_erb__594730326_70277244'
Request

Parameters:

None
```

My overall goal here is to be able to sort records from the observations table based on the last (and first) names of the user model . Note - I am using MS Sql Server for the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think error is here change it like:

```
@observations = Observation.includes(:user).order('users.last_name ASC')
```

Comment: Also, I did not have a user_id column in my model/table. (I had originally been linking to an employee model) Once I added that and changed your line to `@observations = Observation.includes(:user).order('users.last_name ASC')` it worked.